# Putting items from a Perl array into a for loop to print out on HTML

Tags: html, arrays, json, perl, for-loop

I have used Perl to pull keys from JSON data into variables to use in arrays. I want to print out these variables in HTML a table.

I have the variables working but I don't know how to get them to print continuously until there are no more left.

Here is my Perl code. Below this is my HTML which contains the HTML table where I have the data from the array printed. But I have to type each variable in the table to print.

I want it so it will automatically add new rows until there is no more data.

#### Here is the top of the .pl file which is the Perl part

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI qw/:standard/;
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON qw( decode_json );
use LWP::Simple 'get'; 
use Data::Dumper; 

print "content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";

my @sessionArr;
my @classArr;
my @timeArr;
my @adminArr;
my @profArr;
my @descArr;

my $i = 0;

my $myURL = "Leaving URL out for obvious reasons";

my $json = get($myURL);
die "Could not get $myURL!" unless defined $json;

my $decoded_json = decode_json ($json);

my @sessionID = @{ $decoded_json->{'items'} };
foreach my $d ( @sessionID ) {
 $sessionArr[$i] = $d->{"sessionID"};
 $i = $i + 1;
}

$i = 0;

my @class = @{ $decoded_json->{'items'} };
foreach my $d ( @class ) {
 $classArr[$i] = $d->{"classField"};
 $i = $i + 1;
}

$i = 0;


my @time = @{ $decoded_json->{'items'} };
foreach my $d ( @time ) {
  $timeArr[$i] = $d->{"startTimeField"};
  $i = $i + 1;
}

$i = 0;

my @usrcreater = @{ $decoded_json->{'items'} };
foreach my $d ( @usrcreater ) {
  $adminArr[$i] = $d->{"leader"};
  $i = $i + 1;
}

$i = 0;

my @professor = @{ $decoded_json->{'items'} };
foreach my $d ( @professor ) {
  $profArr[$i] = $d->{"professorField"};
  $i = $i + 1;
}

$i = 0;




my @description = @{ $decoded_json->{'items'} };
foreach my $d ( @description ) {
  $descArr[$i] = $d->{"descriptionField"};
  $i = $i + 1;
}

$i = 0;

foreach my $p ( @description ) {
   $i = $i +1;
}
```

**Now here is the table in HTML**

```
<h1>View Study Sessions</h1>

<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<th>Session ID</th>
<th>Course Name</th>
<th>Start Time</th>
<th>Administrator</th>
<th>Instructor</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>$sessionArr[0]</td>
<td>$classArr[0]</td>
<td>$timeArr[0]</td>
<td>$adminArr[0]</td>
<td>$profArr[0]</td>
<td>$descArr[0]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>$sessionArr[1]</td>
<td>$classArr[1]</td>
<td>$timeArr[1]</td>
<td>$adminArr[1]</td>
<td>$profArr[1]</td>
<td>$descArr[1]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>$sessionArr[2]</td>
<td>$classArr[2]</td>
<td>$timeArr[2]</td>
<td>$adminArr[2]</td>
<td>$profArr[2]</td>
<td>$descArr[2]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>$sessionArr[3]</td>
<td>$classArr[3]</td>
<td>$timeArr[3]</td>
<td>$adminArr[3]</td>
<td>$profArr[3]</td>
<td>$descArr[3]</td>
</tr></table> 

<br>
<br>
```

[image]

Here's a screenshot of what I'm  looking at. As you can see the output is on top of the image. I want it to be lower in the page

Comment: Could you show the output of `print Data::Dumper->Dump([$decoded_json], ['decoded_json']);`? At least the first two, three "records"? You can star out (****) the values, if they are somehow confidential. And I promise: the solution is easy :-)

Comment: I just added that line of code to the perl file and opened it in browser but nothing of that nature printed on the browser. is there a way to see what that executes?

Comment: I thought you run that at the command line. Not?

Answer (score 3):

I think your `$decoded_json->{items}` contains an array of hashes (objects) with attributes `sessionID`, `classField`, ….

If that is the case, you can iterate over that array and print the attributes (hash elements) like so:

```
print "<tr>\n";
foreach my $item ( @{ $decoded_json->{'items'} } ) {
    printf( "<td>%s</td>\n", $item->{sessionID} );
    printf( "<td>%s</td>\n", $item->{classField} );
    printf( "<td>%s</td>\n", $item->{startTimeField} );
    printf( "<td>%s</td>\n", $item->{leader} );
    printf( "<td>%s</td>\n", $item->{professorField} );
    printf( "<td>%s</td>\n", $item->{descriptionField} );
}
print "</tr>\n";
```

Comment: So i added what you just mentioned above^ into my perl code.. it does print out on the browser but in a very ugly way. It shows it as plain text with white background on top of my webpage and then under it is the actual html page ..did i do something wrong

Comment: Yes. Of course you have to add the `<h1>`, `<table border...>` stuff yourself. My code only replaces the inner part with the `<tr><td>...</td></tr>`. I didn't know you wanted a completely working cut'n'paste-ready solution. I merely thought you don't know how to iterate over a perl structure.

Comment: No no i know theres more to be done lol. so to add the styling such as margins and headings, i wont be able to do that right in perl code though? i somehow have to extract the output of that code and bring it down to the html part of the file so i can style and stuff, correct?

Comment: Well, I'm currently getting unsure about your intents. I expected you wanted some perl code that is to be run as a .cgi script, fetches data from somewhere and renders it into an HTML table (dynamically). Not true?

Comment: Yes exactly that, i just posted a screenshot so you can see what im referring to

Comment: Ahh, ok. But now you have a different question (_How to render an HTML table properly with some spacing above?_). Please pose a new question for that. If the current question was answered to your liking, please honor @zdim's or my effort.

Comment: Thank you, @Borodin. It wasn't my intention to become pushy. Of course you are right and I'll keep your suggestion in mind. Sounds very reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rewrite that uses [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/index.html) ("TT") to build the HTML page and include the data from your JSON

There are many problems with your original HTML. Tags are unbalanced, and you have head-only elements within the body. I can't guarantee that this fixes everything but I can't spot any more errors. You should be careful to keep your HTML indented so that you can more easily spot unbalanced tags. It also obviates the need to comment the closing tags

I've included a block of code that shows you how to more easily extract arrays of the same field from each of a list of hashes. The variables aren't used, so please delete that code once you've understood the lesson

The templates for Template Toolkit are normally held in separate `.tt` files. In this case I've used the `DATA` file handle as it's more in keeping with the way you wrote your original code. But bear in mind that a TT template may contain `include` statements that refer to other separate files. For instance you could put your footer section in an external file and then `[% INCLUDE footer.tt %]` in your main template. But that is for the future

Note that Template Toolkit allows you to access Perl data structures directly. Anything that the template needs to use must be passed in the second parameter of the `process` methods call. In this case I have passed `{ json => $decoded_json }` so that TT can now use the `json` identifier to refer to the hash that you have downloaded. Within the template, `json.items` is now the array of data (accessible as `json.items.0`, `json.items.1` etc.) and here I have written `[% FOREACH item IN json.items %]` which declares a new TT variable `item` and assigns it to each element of the `items` array in turn

I hope all of that is clear

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings qw/ all FATAL /;

use CGI qw/:standard/;
use JSON qw( decode_json );
use LWP;
use Template;

use Data::Dumper; 

use constant JSON_URL => 'http://example.com/json';

### This code uses a literal JSON data item. The live code should
### fetch the real data from the JSON_URL. The code to do this
### is here but has been commented out

=comment
my $json = do {
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $resp = $ua->get(JSON_URL);
    unless ( $resp->is_success ) {
        die sprintf "Could not retrieve JSON data: %s", $resp->status_line;
    }
    $resp->decoded_content;
};
=cut

my $json = <<END;
{
    "items": [
        {
            "sessionID":        "session1",
            "classField":       "class1",
            "startTimeField":   "start1",
            "leader":           "leader1",
            "professorField":   "prof1",
            "descriptionField": "desc1"
        },
        {
            "sessionID":        "session2",
            "classField":       "class2",
            "startTimeField":   "start2",
            "leader":           "leader2",
            "professorField":   "prof2",
            "descriptionField": "desc2"
        }
    ]
}
END

my $decoded_json = decode_json($json);


### Note that these variables are unused. This is just an example
### of a better way to extract a list of fields from an array
### Please remove this code before deploying

my $items = $decoded_json->{items};

my @sessionArr = map { $_->{sessionID} } @$items;
my @classArr   = map { $_->{classField} } @$items;
my @timeArr    = map { $_->{startTimeField} } @$items;
my @adminArr   = map { $_->{leader} } @$items;
my @profArr    = map { $_->{professorField} } @$items;
my @descArr    = map { $_->{descriptionField} } @$items;

### All that needs to be done its to use CGI to print the HTTP
### header and invoke Template Toolkit to build an HTML page that
### includes the data from the JSON hash

print CGI->header(
    -type    => 'text/html',
    -charset => 'utf-8',
);

my $tt = Template->new;

$tt->process(\*DATA, { json => $decoded_json } );

__DATA__
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>AU Study Sessions</title>

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.png">
    <script src="../js/pace.js"></script>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="preloader"></div>

    <!-- ******************** MASTHEAD SECTION ******************* -->

    <main id="top" class="masthead" role="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href=""><img src="../images/aulogo2.png" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>

            <h1>View Study Sessions</h1>);

            <table>

            [% FOREACH item IN json.items %]
            <tr>
                <td>[% item.sessionID %]</td>
                <td>[% item.classField %]</td>
                <td>[% item.startTimeField %]</td>
                <td>[% item.leader %]</td>
                <td>[% item.professorField %]</td>
                <td>[% item.descriptionField %]</td>
            </tr>
            [% END %]

            <br/>
            <br/>

            <a href=""> Add a Study Session</a>

            <!--
            <a href="index.html#explore" class="scrollto">
                <p>SCROLL DOWN TO EXPLORE</p>
                <p class="scrollto--arrow"><img src="../images/scroll_down.png" alt="scroll down arrow"></p>
            </a>
            -->

        </div> <!-- class="container" -->
    </main>

    <!-- ******************** FOOTER SECTION ******************** -->  

    <div class="container" id="explore">

        <div class="section-title">
            <h2>With Adelphi Study Sessions Website</h2>
            <h4>You will be able to do the following</h4>
        </div>

        <section class="row features">

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_01.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>View Study Groups</h3>
                        <p>See the most up to date study sessions taking place on our garden city campus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_02.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Add and create new study sessions</h3>
                        <p>If you or some classmates want to create a new study session you will be able to add a new group along with course information, sudy topics, and time and location taking place.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_03.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>See description of session</h3>
                        <p>The student who creates the study session will give a short description about what the study session will cover.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_04.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Available on campus</h3>
                        <p>All study sessions will take place on our Garden City campus therefore are available to all students who commute or live on campus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>

        <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/easing.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/nicescroll.js"></script>

    </div> <!-- class="container" id="explore" -->

</body>

</html>
```

#### output

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>AU Study Sessions</title>

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.png">
    <script src="../js/pace.js"></script>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="preloader"></div>

    <!-- ******************** MASTHEAD SECTION ******************* -->

    <main id="top" class="masthead" role="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href=""><img src="../images/aulogo2.png" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>

            <h1>View Study Sessions</h1>);

            <table>


            <tr>
                <td>session1</td>
                <td>class1</td>
                <td>start1</td>
                <td>leader1</td>
                <td>prof1</td>
                <td>desc1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>session2</td>
                <td>class2</td>
                <td>start2</td>
                <td>leader2</td>
                <td>prof2</td>
                <td>desc2</td>
            </tr>


            <br/>
            <br/>

            <a href=""> Add a Study Session</a>

            <!--<a href="index.html#explore" class="scrollto">
            <p>SCROLL DOWN TO EXPLORE</p>
            <p class="scrollto--arrow"><img src="../images/scroll_down.png" alt="scroll down arrow"></p>
            </a> -->

        </div>
    </main>


    <!-- ******************** FOOTER SECTION ******************** -->  
    <div class="container" id="explore">
        <div class="section-title">
            <h2>With Adelphi Study Sessions Website</h2>
            <h4>You will be able to do the following</h4>
        </div>

        <section class="row features">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_01.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>View Study Groups</h3>
                        <p>See the most up to date study sessions taking place on our garden city campus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div><! --/thumbnail -->
            </div><! --/col-sm-6-->

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_02.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Add and create new study sessions</h3>
                        <p>If you or some classmates want to create a new study session you will be able to add a new group along with course information, sudy topics, and time and location taking place.</p>
                    </div>
                </div><! --/thumbnail -->
            </div><! --/col-sm-6-->

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_03.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>See description of session</h3>
                        <p>The student who creates the study session will give a short description about what the study session will cover.</p>
                    </div>
                </div><! --/thumbnail -->
            </div><! --/col-sm-6-->

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_04.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Available on campus</h3>
                        <p>All study sessions will take place on our Garden City campus therefore are available to all students who commute or live on campus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div><! --/thumbnail -->
            </div><! --/col-sm-6-->
        </section><! --/section -->

        <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/easing.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/nicescroll.js"></script> 

    </body>

</html>
```